# Play Framework - how do I get the name of running application mode from application.conf?

Tags: configuration, playframework, development-environment, mode

I am using Play 2.1.3. In the application.conf file I have:

```
%ref1.application.mode=dev
%ref2.application.mode=dev
%ref3.application.mode=dev
```

When I run the application by

```
play run --%ref1
```

I am trying to programmatically getting the mode name --%ref1 which Play has been started with. Is it possible? How can i get the mode "flag name" in the running application?

By the way, I have already tried isDev(), isTest(), is isProd()... I have already managed to detect which mode application is running on but not the name/id of the mode.
Many thanks for some suggestions